# How can I get data in my flask application to not show non existent json values and update accordingly at a certain interval?

Tags: python, api, flask, python-requests

I've set up a flask application running on Heroku that checks an API for train information via parameters passed in the URL.

The main lookup part of the function is in this function:

```
train_service_data = {}
train_station_data = {}

dest = 0
origin = 0
mytimes = 0
myurl = 0


def checker():
    global mytrains  # modifies the global copy of mytrains otherwise a new variable is created
    global myurl
    global mytimes
    # myurl = f"http://huxley.apphb.com/all/{origin}/to/{dest}/{mytimes}"
    response = requests.get(myurl, params={"accessToken": SECRET_KEY})
    response.raise_for_status()  # this makes an error if something failed
    data1 = response.json()
    mytrains['departure'] = str(data1['crs'])
    mytrains['arrival'] = str(data1['filtercrs'])
    try:
        found_service = 0
        for index, service in enumerate(data1['trainServices']):  # indexes data for pulling of previous values
            if service['std'].replace(':', '') in mytimes:n
                found_service += 1
                train = SimpleNamespace(
                    serviceID=str(service['serviceID']),
                    arrival_time=str(service['std']),
                    estimated_arrival=str(service['etd']),
                    status='On time'
                )
                prior_service = data1['trainServices'][index - 1]
                if train.estimated_arrival == 'Cancelled':
                    train.status = 'Cancelled'
                    train.alternate_service = str(prior_service['std'])
                    train.alternate_status = str(prior_service['etd'])
                elif train.estimated_arrival != 'On time':
                    train.status = 'Delayed'
                write_index = index
                for i, v in mytrains.items():
                    if isinstance(v, dict) and v['arrival_time'] == train.arrival_time:
                        write_index = i
                mytrains[write_index] = train.__dict__
            elif found_service == 0:  # if no service is found
                mytrains['state'] = 'The services currently available are not specified in user_time.'
    except (TypeError, AttributeError) as error:
        mytrains['errorMessage'] = 'There is no train service data'
    try:
        NRCCRegex = re.compile('^(.*?)[\.!\?](?:\s|$)')  # regex pulls all characters until hitting a . or ! or ?
        myline = NRCCRegex.search(data1['nrccMessages'][0]['value'])  # regex searches through nrccMessages
        mytrains['nrcc'] = myline.group(1)  # prints parsed NRCC message
    except (TypeError, AttributeError) as error:  # tuple catches multiple errors, AttributeError for None value
        mytrains['nrcc'] = 'No NRCC'
    return mytrains
```

This then gets split into the location and actual services messages via the following two functions:

```
def time_trains_services():  # splits data into train services lookup
    global train_service_data
    train_service_data = [j for i, j in mytrains.items() if isinstance(j, dict)]  # grabs train service data into dict
    return train_service_data


def time_trains_location():  # splits data into crs, filtercrs and nrcc queries
    global train_station_data
    train_station_data = {i: j for i, j in mytrains.items() if not isinstance(j, dict)}  # grabs [0] data into separate dict
    return train_station_data
```

These functions provide dicts that are put into Flask, but when the page is refreshed, other values in the json are displayed, that are not the ones I've specifically earmarked with `if service['std'].replace(':', '') in mytimes:`

My template logic is as follows:

```
        <div class="train_times">
            {% for services in trainservices %}
                {% if services.status != 'On time' and services.status != 'Cancelled' %}
                    <p>{{services.arrival_time}} -> {{services.estimated_arrival}}</p>
                    {% if not loop.last %}
                        |
                    {% endif %}
                {% endif %}
                {% if services.status == 'On time' %}
                    <p>{{services.arrival_time}} ({{services.status}})</p>
                    {% if not loop.last %}
                        |
                    {% endif %}
                {% endif %}
                {% if traindata.status == 'Cancelled' %}
                    <p>The previous service is: <span>{{ trainsevices.alternate_service }}</span></p>
                    <p>The previous train arrives at: <span>{{ alternate_status }}</span></p>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
```

Why are the other times that I've not specifically defined showing up? How can I prevent this from happening, I've considered `dict.clear()` but I'm not sure this is the right way to go about this.

The times also remain on the page once the json no longer contains them when I refresh the page, I've tried setting up APScheduler, to run every minute, but this didn't solve my issue.

Any help is much appreciated! As always, I can provide more code if something is unclear.

EDIT: Added the full code as it is now to fill in any missing gaps: https://paste.pydis.com/inudurodah.py

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Took a look at the updated question and found some possible issues.

Issues with parameter handling:

- The app currently does not seem to split `mytimes` (a comma-separated string) into an actual list. It should convert `mytimes` to a list and validate that the items are in correct format (4-digit times separated by commas), alerting the user if otherwise.
- Additionally, when `mytimes` is not specified, the app will report that 'The services currently available are not specified in user_time.' This is misleading. If no times are selected then either *all* available times should be listed, *or* the app should respond that it's necessary to specify at least one time.
- There's no validation that all parameters are provided, which is necessary if they're going to all be stuffed into the URL (an unprovided parameter will be interpolated as 'None' in the string).
- If the access key needs to be in environment variable `DARWIN_KEY`, then the app should complain if it's not found. Using just `os.environ.get` will just let the failure happen later, which makes it harder to detect.

Issues with using the use of global variables:

- The global variables used can end up being shared by multiple requests.
  This is easy to show by performing one request after another when threading is enabled in Flask (which it is by default -- see http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/), and seeing data is 'polluted' by previous requests.
- In order to avoid global variables, split the flow into multiple functions, each which take a few inputs and return what's needed
- All the necessary info is already in trainservices and location info -- so there is no need to also provide the nested and redundant structure, `mytrains`.

Another possible issue:

- `service['std']` can be None, in which case `.replace` won't work on it

Here's a guideline for how you might avoid all the `globals` (assuming you do not want to share that state among requests, which sounds like it's the case). It's not tested and just a guideline:

```
# do all the imports 

app = Flask(__name__)


def retrieve_service_info(request_args):
    """request_args a Flask.request.args type"""
    origin = request_args.get('origin')
    dest = request_args.get('dest')
    mytimes = request_args.get('mytimes')

    url = f"http://huxley.apphb.com/all/{origin}/to/{dest}/{mytimes}"
    response = requests.get(url, params={"accessToken": get_secret_key()})
    response.raise_for_status()

    return response.json()


def get_secret_key():
    # fail here if key not found?
    return os.environ.get('DARWIN_KEY', None)


def processed_train_service(service):
    def get_status(estimated_arrival):
        if estimated_arrival in ('On time', 'Cancelled'):
            return estimated_arrival
        else:
            return 'Delayed'

    return {'serviceID': service['serviceID'],
            'arrival_time': service['std'],
            'estimated_arrival': service['etd'],
            'status': get_status(service['etd'])}


def get_train_summary(service_info):
    #service_info = retrieve_service_info(request_args)
    train_services = service_info['trainServices']
    summary = [processed_train_service(service) for service
               in train_services if service['std'] is not None]

    # fill in alternative service as previous service
    # for any cancelled service where there is a previous service
    for i, service in enumerate(summary[1:]):
        if service['status'] == 'Cancelled':
            previous_service = summary[i-1]
            service['alternate_service'] = str(previous_service['arrival_time'])
            service['alternate_status'] = str(previous_service['estimated_arrival'])
    return summary


def get_location_data(service_info):
    """function just to get data related to the station"""
    def get_nrcc(info):
        try:
            NRCCRegex = re.compile('^(.*?)[\.!\?](?:\s|$)')  # regex pulls all characters until hitting a . or ! or ?
            myline = NRCCRegex.search(info['nrccMessages'][0]['value'])  # regex searches through nrccMessages
            return myline.group(1)  # prints parsed NRCC message
        except (TypeError, AttributeError) as error:  # tuple catches multiple errors, AttributeError for None value
            print('error -> %s' % (error,))
            return 'No NRCC'

    return {'departure': service_info['crs'],
            'arrival': service_info['filtercrs'],
            'nrcc': get_nrcc(service_info)}


@app.route("/getstatus", methods=["GET"])
def status_check():
    service_info = retrieve_service_info(request.args)

    train_summary = get_train_summary(service_info)
    location_summary = get_location_data(service_info)

    return render_template('train_index.html', trainstation=location_summary, trainservices=train_summary)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a go. When you say before `render_template` function,  do you mean in my `status_check()` function? I've also added the full code as it is currently, before implementing your suggestion. I'll have a go at re-writing this without global variables!

Comment: I've added your code into status_check() but it's now throwing up `KeyError: 1` for `del train_service_data[k]`